# Laravel Query Builder - Multi-where clause

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

How can you do this where clause in query builder?

```
WHERE
    (ENTRY_MODE = 'ACTUAL' AND r.YEAR BETWEEN '2011' AND '2014')
    OR
    (ENTRY_MODE = 'BUDGETED' AND r.YEAR = '2014')
```

Here is my current code

```
->where(function($query) use($year, $yearFrom, $yearTo){
    $query->where(function($query) use ($year){
        $query->where('eh.ENTRY_MODE', 'BUDGETED')
        ->where('r.YEAR', $year)
    })->orWhere(function($query) use ($yearFrom, $yearTo){
        $query->where('eh.ENTRY_MODE', 'ACTUAL')
        ->whereIn('r.YEAR', array($yearFrom, $yearTo))
    })
})
```

The code above gives me a `syntax error, unexpected '}'` on the line 5 (or Where part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a `semicolons` problem, try this:

```
->where(function($query) use($year, $yearFrom, $yearTo){
        $query->where(function($query) use ($year){
            $query->where('eh.ENTRY_MODE', 'BUDGETED')
            ->where('r.YEAR', $year); //<--semicolon here
        })->orWhere(function($query) use ($yearFrom, $yearTo){
            $query->where('eh.ENTRY_MODE', 'ACTUAL')
            ->whereIn('r.YEAR', array($yearFrom, $yearTo)); //<--semicolon here
        }); //<--semicolon here
    }); //<-- and one last semicolon here if this is the end of your chain.
```

Comment: Oh missed that! thank you! I thought it was okay not to include the semicolon.